# Removing items from array list without using position

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, android-recyclerview

Morning everyone

Currently I have an ArrayList which allows me to remove by a set of item position which is perfect in most situations. But I was wondering if it was possible to remove my something e.g. a long variable.

My current ArrayList which is currently set on my recyclerView adapter.

```
private ArrayList<NoteInfoModal> mAdapter = new ArrayList (List)
```

Under the NoteInfoModal we also have the getters and setters for multiple rows that I use for my recyclerView e.g. Name, Description, Col ID etc...

Removing an item at the moment I simply use the following code below

```
mAdapter.remove(position)
```

Is there a way of altering this ArrayList so I can for example delete a result from this arraylist without using the position but instead an item inside the arraylist e.g. col id?

Thank you

Comment: you can remove either by position or by the object itself. If you want to remove by some field of the object (`e.g. col id`), then you first have to find the object with that col id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you will have to run a for-each loop for that.

```html
//suppose you have col_Id;
for(NoteInfoModel noteInfoModel : mAdapter) {
  if(noteInfoModel.getColId == col_Id) {
    mAdapter.remove(noteInfoModel);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: But would I be right in thinking that if had a large amount of results then this could cause the app to lag?

Comment: use `notifyItemRemoved` and IIRC also `notifyItemRangeChanged` which updates the RecyclerView without any lag.

Comment: it will throw an concurrent modification please check

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859)

Comment: Worked in my code, as I couldn't get my head around implementing hashcode into my recyclerView

Comment: TakeInfo any way of removing that one row and the previous row as there is a 1 Col_Id difference between them?

Comment: Yes, you have to maintain previous object. Like this.    //suppose you have col_Id;
    for(NoteInfoModel noteInfoModel : mAdapter) {
NodeInfoModel prevModel;
      if(noteInfoModel.getColId == col_Id) {
        mAdapter.remove(noteInfoModel);
        if(prevModel != null)
               mAdapter.remove(prevModel);
        break;
      }
      prevModel = nodeInfoModel;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Sure, instead of using the position to remove, you simply put in the Object you want to remove from the ArrayList:

```
mAdapter.remove(yourObject)
```

take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-).

**Ganesh Gudghe** also mentioned, that its neccessary to implement hashCode() and equals() for your class NoteInfoModal.

Comment: before you need to @Override hashCode() and equals()

Comment: follow up question to your response arnoduebel if put for example mAdapter.remove(ID) I get the response (may not contain objects of type) and row isn't removed

Comment: like Ganesh Gudghe mentioned, its neccessary to implement hashCode() and equals() for your class NoteInfoModal. Edited my Answer

Comment: Can't say I've used them before, but still learning. I will do my research